# How to end the function of a button after the first true if statement has been executed?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this button that I want to use to change an image to the next one in the pattern. However, as soon as it executes and finds the if statement that is true it will instantly make the following if statement true and will cycle streight through to the end.

```
@IBAction func addone(_ sender: UIButton) {

if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones0") {
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones1")}
if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones1") {
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones2")}
if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones2") {
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones3")}
if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones3") {
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones4")}
if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones4") {
```

How do I make the code stop, after it has executed the first true if statement, until the next time the button is clicked?

Comment: You can use `else if` instead of `if`, but you shouldn't compare images. That will not work. The comparisons might be false even if the image data is equal.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an `if`  - `else if` chain. The first evaluation to `true` skips the rest of the chain:

```
if a == b { 
   ... 
} else if a == c { 
   ... 
} else if a == d { 
   ... 
} 
else { ... } // optional
```

An alternative is a `switch`, the behavior is the same as `if - else if`

```
switch onesimage.image {
  case UIImage(named: "ones0"): ...
  case UIImage(named: "ones1"): ...
  default: break

}
```

Be aware that creating a lot of `UIImage` instances and compare them is unnecessarily expensive.

---

However it's much more efficient (and easier) to use an index which is incremented. If the maximum value is reached the index is reset to zero.

```
var imageIndex = 0
let maxIndex = 4

@IBAction func addone(_ sender: UIButton) {

   imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % maxIndex
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones\(imageIndex)")
}
```

---

or if the image names cannot be serialized use an array containing the names

```
var imageIndex = 0
let imageNames = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]

@IBAction func addone(_ sender: UIButton) {

   imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % imageNames.count
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: imageNames[imageIndex])
}
```

Comment: While this is absolutely the better solution overall, it doesn't actually answer the question being asked. I propose you add a little update to the start of the answer explaining how using `if/else` is what is needed to solve the initial issue, then say "but, here is a much better solution".

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly speaking, you can imagine your code executed line by line from top to bottom:

```
doA() // executed first
doB() // executed second
doC() // executed third
```

At some point that is not enough, you need conditional execution, for this in Swift there are [control flow statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120). For example, if you want to do something if some expression is true and avoid doing something otherwise you can use `if` control flow statement.

The most basic usage of `if` goes like this:

```
let variable = true
if variable {
    doSomething()
}
```

That is, if expression `variable` evaluates to `true`, (and it always evaluates to true, because it is defined as such) method `doSomething` gets executed. Now let's do something else after `if` expression:

```
let variable = true
if variable {
    doSomething()
}
doSomethingElse()
```

Execution goes from top to bottom, at first boolean `variable` is defined and assigned value of `true`. After that value is compared with `true` and as it is `true` execution enters the so called "if branch", i.e. code that should be done on condition and `doSomething` is executed. Now, execution reaches the end of the branch and jumps to the first line after the closing bracket "}". `doSomethingElse` is executed and it doesn't matter if `variable` was true or false:

```
let variable = false
if variable {
    doSomething()
}
// still executed
doSomethingElse()
```

because it is on the next line. And execution goes line by line.

If we wanted to make sure, that on some condition only one of `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` got executed, we need to change the code. There's extended `if` statement version:

```
let variable = true
if variable {
    // so called "true branch" starts
    doSomething()
    // "true branch" ends
}
else {
    // so called "false branch" or "else branch" starts
    doSomethingElse()
   // "false branch" or "else branch" ends
}
```

if `variable` is `true` `doSomething` is executed, if `variable` is `false` `doSomethingElse` is executed.

You can add more conditions to the same `if` statement and they will be checked from top to bottom, first condition evaluated to `true` is executed:

```
let variable = 42
if variable == 42 {
    // the meaning of life
}
else if variable > 5 {
    // more then 5
}
else {
    // not 42 and <= 5
}
```

as you can see there are two conditions that are true, `variable == 42` and `variable > 5`, the first one (from top to bottom) is executed, then execution jumps after the last closing bracket.

Now I must address your statements, you make decisions based on:

```
...
if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones0") {
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones1")
}
...
```

you compare `UIImage` instances. While `UIImage(named:)` may return same instances for the same name, it is not guarantied to do so. So your checks may fail and your app won't work as expected.

It is generally a bad practice to store state in the UI. I suggest to have some variable somewhere (for example in your view controller) and update images based on it's value.

For example:

```
var imageIndex = 0
let maxImageIndex = 4

@IBAction func addone(_ sender: UIButton) {
   imageIndex = imageIndex + 1
   if imageIndex > maxImageIndex {
       imageIndex = 0
   }

   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones\(imageIndex)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use ladder if else structure, when any of the condition gets satisfy, rest of will only check but would not get satisfy.

Also you should write your code in readable format, So help you to understand much.

```
    @IBAction func addone(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones0")
        {
            onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones1")
        }
        else if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones1")
        {
            onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones2")
        }
        else if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones2")
        {
            onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones3")
        }
        else if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones3")
        {
            onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones4")
        }
        else if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones4")
        {
            onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones5")
        }

    }
```

Read
http://www.techcrashcourse.com/2015/05/c-programming-if-else-ladder-statement.html

Answer (score -1):

There are two choices. Either use `else if`

```
if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones0") {
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones1")
} else if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones1") {
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones2")
} else if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones2") {
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones3")
} else if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones3") {
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones4")
} else if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones4") {
```

Or use `return`

```
if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones0") {
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones1")
   return
}
if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones1") {
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones2")
   return
}
if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones2") {
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones3")
   return
}
if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones3") {
   onesimage.image = UIImage(named: "ones4")
   return
}
if onesimage.image == UIImage(named: "ones4") {
```